# Can I have one column for two different values with foreign key from two different tables?

Tags: sql, database

So I have this table **Addresses**:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
Address_ID VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
Student_ID/Staff_Number VARCHAR (20),
Name CHAR (50),
Surname CHAR (30),
Building/House_Number INT (5),
Street CHAR (20),
City CHAR (30),
Postcode VARCHAR (10)
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students (Student_ID)
);
```

The thing is the line `Student_ID/Staff_Number VARCHAR (20),` is either coming from students table or staff table. So can I assign two foreign keys?

Comment: "Multiple values related to different tables in a single column is the path to the dark side…Multiple values related to different tables in a single column leads to anger…anger leads to hate…hate leads to suffering" - Every DBA Ever

Comment: Wrong direction. Put addressid in students table with a fk, and in staff table too.

Comment: @jarlh Also consider having `student_address` and `staff_address` tables in order to save multiple addresses (`home`, `work`, etc.) per user type.

Comment: @jarlh Completely agreed.  Gave a few options in my answer, and that was my personal recommendation.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this is less of a "how do I do specific thing X?" and more of a "How *should* I be doing this?"

Because, to be honest, you *don't* want to do it the way you're trying to lay out.

Let me give you some alternatives that are better from a database layout perspective:

1. **Reverse the relationship (my recommendation).**  Instead of the Address table tying to the Staff/Student, have the Staff/Student
   tying to an AddressID.
2. **Consolidate the two tables into a person table** (another very good choice).  That way, you only have one table that the Address table is linking to.  Then, if certain fields are applicable to only one *type* of person (staff-only, student-only, etc) - offload *only* those columns into a dedicated table for only those fields.  So you might have a Person table with all the basic info, an Address table that links to the Person table, a Student table with a GradeLevel column, and a Staff table with a SubjectTaught column.
3. **Have two separate address tables: one for students, one for staff.**  Want to link over to the students table?  Great - you've
   got the StudentID in the StudentAddress table.  And the same with
   the Staff.
4. **Have a column indicating the AddresseeType.**  0 for Students, 1 for Staff.  Don't put the foreign key constraint in at all.
5. **Have two separate columns - one for the student ID, one for the staff ID** (presumably, one will always be null.)  Make them both a
   foreign key to the respective table (foreign keys can have null
   values.)

... all of these sound better than trying to make a split-foreign-key.  Worse, what happens if a student and a staff member share an ID?  Which entity does that address apply to?

Comment: Or have one common table for both staff and students. (Some grad school students teach too.)

Comment: @jarlh - good point.  I think I'll expand on that a bit and add it to the list

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To make sure they have unique IDs. I have to have two different tables for students and staff so I'll go with two different tables for addresses, I guess. Does it make it more complicated as I am trying to do it the simplest way possible?

Comment: Honestly, the simplest is to just reverse the table relationship.  Instead of having the address point to the Student/Staff tables, just have the Student/Staff tables point to the Address table.  Have an AddressID identifier in your address table, and have both of the other tables have an AddressID column that points to it..

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

You would probably be looking at implementing some kind of inheritance pattern in your design where you have something like a 'person' base table which both student and staff tables extend and the foreign key points to that instead.

P.S. Is your varchar Ids columns the clustered indexes? This can be bad for performance, consider a surrogate identity column for clustering

Answer (score -1):

You can always add multiple foreign key constraints on a single column but **ALL** of them will be enforced, not just one of them. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
Address_ID VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
Student_ID VARCHAR (20),
Name CHAR (50),
Surname CHAR (30),
Building/House_Number INT (5),
Street CHAR (20),
City CHAR (30),
Postcode VARCHAR (10),
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students (Student_ID)
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Staff (Staff_ID)
);
```

This is probably not what you want. Probably what you want is to have two columns, each one pointing to a separate table; and for those to columns one is always `null` and the other one is not null. You can do this as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
Address_ID VARCHAR (10) PRIMARY KEY,
Student_ID VARCHAR (20),
Staff_ID VARCHAR(20),
Name CHAR (50),
Surname CHAR (30),
Building/House_Number INT (5),
Street CHAR (20),
City CHAR (30),
Postcode VARCHAR (10),
FOREIGN KEY (Student_ID) REFERENCES Students (Student_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES Staff (Staff_ID),
constraint ct1 check (Student_ID is null and Staff_ID is not null
                   or Student_ID is not null and Staff_ID is null)
);
```

The constraint `ct1` makes sure one and only one of them is "active" at any given point in time.